# Python intersection inconsistent occurrence order

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a list of datetime separators of a string in the same order that they occur int it.

Suppose I have the following datetime: `2015-03-25 12:22:21`; the output I intend to get from `set().intersection` is a list like this: `['-', ' ']`

The problem is that it comes reversed. It seems random. Take a look at the following outputs:

```
[IN]: list(set('/|.-T ').intersection('2015-03-25 12:22:21'))
[OUT]: [' ', '-']
```

Now, this one comes correct:

```
[IN]: list(set('/|.-T ').intersection('2015-03-25T12:22:21'))`
[OUT]: ['-', 'T']
```

Why does the first one comes reversed with the space first? How can I approach this to get a consistent order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that preserves the original order of the separators and doesn't output duplicate separators. When duplicates are present only the first one is included in the output.

```
def date_separators(datestring, seps):
    out = []
    for s in datestring:
        if s in seps and s not in out:
            out.append(s)
    return out

# test

data = (
    '2015-03-25 12:22:21',
    '2015-03-25T12:22:23',
    '5/6/2016 12:22:25 ',
)

seps = frozenset('/|.-T ')
for s in data:
    print(s, date_separators(s, seps))
```

**output**

```
2015-03-25 12:22:21 ['-', ' ']
2015-03-25T12:22:23 ['-', 'T']
5/6/2016 12:22:25  ['/', ' ']
```

Answer (score 3):

[set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) does not maintain order, You have to achieve it by looping

```
output = []
for i in '2015-03-25 12:22:21':
    if i not in output and i in '/|.-T ']:
        output.append(i)
```

Output:

```
['-', ' ']
```

Comment: It will be faster to do the `in` test against a set though. So you can do something like `seps = set('/|.-T ')` before the list comp. Do not put that `set` call inside the list comp, though, because that would get re-executed for each char in the input string.

Comment: "It will be faster to do the `in` test against a set" that is technically not true. It will be faster for huge sets, since it has a constant computational complexity. But constant does not always mean lowest possible.

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow Good point. I *think* 6 chars is enough for set to be faster. IIRC, it is for set vs list, but I can't remember the crossover point for set vs str.